# LINE の OGP のリッチ表示についての質問です。

Tags: php, html, line-opengraph, opengraph

WordPress ブログに、 LINE, Facebook, Twitter に OGP を適応させたいのですが、 LINE だけうまく表示されません。

コードが悪いのかと思い、別の WordPress サイトに同じ OGP コードとリンクを設置しましたが、普通に LINE も表示されました。 検索しても LINE の OGP について詳しく書いている記事を私の力では見つけることができませんでした。

WordPress 側の設定が何かLINEの表示を邪魔しているのでしょうか？  
詳しい方が居ましたらお手数をおかけしますが、解決にご協力いただければと思います。

参考までに OGP を記載したコードを貼っておきます。（xxxで隠している箇所は絶対パスで記載しています。）

```html
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?>｜<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name') ; ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="xxx" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
 <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php get_featured_image_url(); ?>" />
 <?php } else { ?>
 <meta property="og:image" content="xxx.png" />
 <?php } ?>
 <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
 <meta name="twitter:title" content="<?php wp_title('&laquo;', true, 'right'); ?>">
 <meta name="twitter:description" content="xxx">
 <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="<?php get_featured_image_url(); ?>">
 <?php } else { ?>
 <meta name="twitter:image" content="xxx.png">
 <?php } ?>
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;t=<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><img src="xxx.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="twitter://post?message=<?php the_title(); ?>（<?php the_permalink(); ?>）"><img src="xxx.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="line://msg/text/<?php the_title(); ?>%0D%0A<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="xxx.png" alt="LINEで送る" /></a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: 「LINE だけうまく表示されません」とは、具体的にどういう状況ですか？期待する結果と、実際の状況（○○が表示されない、とか、押したけど何も起こらない、とか）を教えて頂けると良いかと思います。

Comment: >>Yoichiro Tanaka 様
<head></head>内で指定したOGP設定が読み込まれていない状態です。
タイムライン投稿時にリンクを追加で問題の起きているURLを記載するとURLは表示されて飛ぶ事もできるのですが、サムネイル画像、タイトル、ディスクリプションが取得されていません。

こちらでも検証を続けていたのですが、違うドメインでファイルとデータベースをインポートしてテストを行ったところ、タイムラインにサムネイル、タイトル、ディスクリプションが表示されました。
OGPの設定が問題ではないのがわかりましたが、何が問題なのか見当がつかなくなりました。
問題の起きているドメインは（ドメイン.red）です。
検証を行い成功したドメインは（ドメイン.com）(ドメイン.co.jp)です。
長文になり申し訳ありません。

Comment: 補足：新しく作ったドメイン.redにインポートを行うと、問題の起きているドメイン同様タイムラインにはURLしか表示されませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記の内容で思いつく原因として、以下が考えられそうです。

- 「LINEで送る」Buttonでは認識されないTop level domainだった。

それ以外の理由は、ちょっと思いつきません。

Comment: 私もそこが濃厚だと思い先日LINEにお問い合わせ致しました。
.redが比較的新しいドメインなので対応できていなのも納得できます。
それに関しての質問を出していたのですが、Tanaka様と同じ回答でした。
新しいドメインを用意し、リダイレクトで今回の問題を解決しようと思います。
ご返答ありがとうございました。